Day Trips from Tbilisi? Which towns are accessible by public transport?
Soon I’ll be going to Tbilisi and staying there for around 2 weeks. To avoid spending all 2 weeks in Tbilisi, I’m looking for day trips to nearby towns, villages or nature destinations.
I am looking for something that is easily accessible via public transport. Searching on the internet, I found some suggestions like Mtskheta, Sighnaghi and Gori. However, it is difficult to find information on which ones are worth visiting for a single-day trip and whether they are accessible by public transport and how. Apparently, there are trains and minibuses that go to these destinations but I wasn’t able to find detailed information on schedules and it’s not clear which trips will be easier. I could use some advice from a local or someone who has done it before.

Mtskheta is definitely worth visiting but you will need a car to go to the Jvari Monastery
Gori is probably not worth visiting unless you want to see Stalin Museum.
Minibuses for Mtskheta and Gori leave from Didube bus station
Sighnaghi is a nice town to visit but if you want to go that far it makes more sense to also visit Telavi on the way and spend a night or two there. Also, visit the Tsinandali museum while you are there (15 minute drive from Telavi) and nearby churches (Gremi, Nekresi, Alaverdi). Minibuses for Telavi and Sighnaghi depart from Ortachala Bus Station.
I also recommend visiting Stepantsminda (previously called Kazbegi) but you will need to spend one night there as it's a bit further (3-4 hours by car). Minibuses depart from Didube.

Mtskheta is my number one pick based on this information. Is it worth visiting even without the Jvari Monastery?

@hb20007 Yes, it's worth visiting. By the way, WikiTravel says it's possible to walk/climb to Jvari if you are feeling adventurous and energetic. Haven't tried it myself :)

This suggestions are great and quite easy to access by public transportation called Marshutka, which is a mini bus. I think you can book tickets online, but one suggestion I have is to get to the station little early than scheduled if you want to choose a good seat; you cannot book a specific place.
Also I would recommend visiting Batumi, which is a really beautiful city by the sea. It has many beautiful sights, like the Ali and Nino statue and the botanical garden, though you can also visit a botanical garden in Tbilisi.
And one more piece of advice: even though traveling by public transportation is quite cheap, if you are planning to visit multiple cities and you want to have a flexible schedule so you can travel whenever you want I would recommend you to book a car with starcar.
Before you start exploring other cities, though, I would definitely recommend seeing everything in Tbilisi. Believe me, it has quite a lot to offer!
